# How to get value of templated objects in typescript that references another object?

Tags: typescript, object

I'm a beginner in typescript and I'm trying to understand the best way to achieve this in typescript?

So I have a **map** object which is field mapping to merge two objects **source**, **target** in this case.

The map object cannot be altered and the `"${source}.field1"` will always be a string format

```
source = { "field1" : 10, "field3" : 30}
target = { "field2" : 20, "field4" : 40}

map = {
      "JuncField1":"${source}.field1",
      "JuncField2":"${target}.field2"
}
```

The aim is to create a new object as below with the above mapping. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
{ "JuncField1" : 10, "JuncField2" : 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is actually pretty close to what you want.

```
var source = { "field1" : 10, "field3" : 30}
var target = { "field2" : 20, "field4" : 40}

var map = {
      "JuncField1": source.field1,
      "JuncField2": target.field2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately "${source}.field1" is the string format in which it will be received and I need to convert and store in map object as source.field1. I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the either source object or target object, grab same key from target and source and put it in map object.

```
const mapObject = {};
for (let key in targetObject) {
  mapObject[key] = { ["taget-" + key]: targetObject[key], ["source-" + key]: sourceObject[key] };
}

// mapObject Will Be Look Like
/*
{
 "field1":{"target-field1":10,"source-field1":20},
 "field2":{"target-field2":20,"source-field2":30}
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to share a code snippet? I'm concerned about converting "${source}.field1" to source.field1 (through regex etc)

Comment: Hi @GaneshRajasekar i have edited my answer with code, check it out. I am assuming that target and source objects contain same keys.